# Question about programming, not a programming language

Tags: discussion

Is it accepted to write a question about programming itself on Stack Overflow, rather than something specific about a certain programming language?

For example:

> What, if any, is the correct "way" to program, that applies to all
>   languages?

Comment: Can you give us some more details on what you're wanting to ask? Without more specifics, it's really hard to tell if your question would fall into the scope of Stack Overflow, or if it might fit on another site on the network, or if it isn't a great question for the network at all.

Comment: It depends on the scope of the question.  This is what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  That specific quesiton is _way_ __too broad__ (and too opinion-based).

Comment: *What, if any, is the correct "way" to program, that applies to all languages* is not reliably answerable in any format in this universe.

Comment: This is really already answered in the Help Center, but my take on it is, if you are trying to make something work and having a problem, then it goes on SO.  If you want to discuss theories, or multiple ways to perform an algorithm, it probably belongs on another site in the network.

Comment: @Claies Well, we have the [tag:algorithm] and the [tag:laguage-agnostic] tags. No need to be language specifi on SO generally.

Comment: There are examples of popular, on-topic questions that are language agnostic, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern. Still, many questions that are language agnostic are also off topic and should either be closed or migrated. For instance, in the R tag we get lots of questions about statistics, which we migrate to crossvalidated.com.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's the point I was trying to make.  It's not really about the language you are using, it's about the question you are asking.  "My Algorithm doesn't work" is much different than "Which algorithm is better"....

Comment: @Claies _"it probably belongs on another site in the network"_ And that's the point of your comment I was disagreeing with.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't say every question belongs on another site, just based on the content of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends, but I've seen few good questions stem from this.

In certain cases, questions about programming are on topic on SO that don't directly relate to any programming language, or relate to more than one programming language.  There are [two very popular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1079354) examples of [questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/1079354) either don't relate to a specific language, or relate to more than one language.

In the vast majority of cases that I've seen, questions that usually broach this subject are incredibly broad and not suitable to be asked anywhere in the network.

Take, for instance, your question:

> What, if any, is the correct "way" to program, that applies to all languages.

That is ***entirely*** too broad.  Notwithstanding the different programming paradigms that exist, not all languages support all things or concepts.  Further, the nuance of "correct" is one that you'll get into arguments behind; a veteran (25+ years) engineer may have different opinions than mid-level engineer, and at that point it becomes a shouting match.

If you're going to ask a language-agnostic question, do your best to make it clear, concise, and on-topic.  Don't let it be subject to as many answers as possible; keep the scope narrow and clear.

Comment: Not only is that question too broad, it should probably be held up as the *definition* of too broad somewhere :)

Comment: alright, this clears it up for me, should I edit the title to have [solved] at the beginning?

Comment: NO!  I mean....no.  That's not necessary.  Using the "accept" checkmark is enough.

Answer (score 4):

> *"Is it accepted to write a question about programming itself ..."*

What do you actually mean with *programming itself*?

From your sample

> ```
> What, if any, is the correct "way" to program, that applies to all languages.
> ```

This would be a ***too-broad*** or ***opinion based*** question even without any language specific (or the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)) tags applied.

There's no single *correct way* to program. *Correctness* is highly dependent on your actual programming language/environment you use.

Detailed descriptions for the mentioned close (off-topic) reasons are available here:

[What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)